# Multiple Selects on Insert Statement - mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

1.

```
**code**
id
name
```

2.

```
**code_category**
id
code_id
category_id
discount
```

I have a list of 15000 codes in the database without the code_category yet. I only have 1 sample one to reference in code_category. I have to mass add in the code_category with 20 categories per code.

I am thinking of left joining both tables to get where code_id is null that gets me all the un-attached codes but I need another select statement to get the 20 different types of code_category rows to enter per code.

```
insert into code_category (code_id, category_id, discount)
values
    (select id from code c
    left join code_category cc on cc.code_id = c.id
    where cc.code_id is null)
    union 
    (select categoryid, discount from code_category where c.id = 123)
```

123 being the reference id.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: i apologise, updated. i did rack my brains

Comment: In your select you need to provide values for each column named in the insert. You are only supplying a value for code_id. The union doesn't make sense. If you have a select with a union, both selects have to return the same number/type of columns

Comment: Suggestion: Run just the select part to see what it returns.

Answer (score 0):

I built a simplified example of your tables in a SQL Fiddle, then ran just the select (shown below) to see what rows would be inserted. See if this example answers your question.

Note how in the select I left join twice, once to get a list of categories, and again to find the missing ones.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad74739/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `code` (
    `id`            INT(11) UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name`          VARCHAR(50)         NULL        DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT '';

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `code_category` (
    `id`            INT(11) UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `codeid`        INT(11) UNSIGNED    NULL        DEFAULT NULL,
    `categoryid`    INT(11) UNSIGNED    NULL        DEFAULT NULL,
    `discount`      INT(11) UNSIGNED    NULL        DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `idx_codecategory_catid` (`categoryid`),
    KEY `idx_codecategory_codeid` (`codeid`)
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT '';

INSERT INTO `code`
(`id`,`name`)
VALUES
(1,'code1'),
(2,'code2'),
(3,'code3'),
(4,'code4');

INSERT INTO `code_category`
(`codeid`,`categoryid`,`discount`)
VALUES
(1,1,3),
(2,1,2),
(1,2,2),
(1,3,3),
(1,4,2),
(1,5,2),
(1,6,2),
(1,7,2),
(1,8,2),
(1,9,2),
(1,10,2),
(1,11,2),
(1,12,2),
(1,13,2),
(1,14,2),
(1,15,2),
(1,16,2),
(1,17,2),
(1,18,2),
(1,19,2),
(1,20,2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
        c.id,
        cc1.codeid,
        cc1.categoryid, 
        cc1.discount
    FROM code c
    LEFT JOIN code_category cc1
        ON cc1.codeid = 1
    LEFT JOIN code_category cc
        ON cc.codeid = c.id AND cc.codeid = cc1.codeid
    WHERE cc.codeid is null
  ORDER BY c.id,cc1.codeid,cc1.categoryid
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad74739/2/0)**:

```
| id | codeid | categoryid | discount |
|----|--------|------------|----------|
|  2 |      1 |          1 |        3 |
|  2 |      1 |          2 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |          3 |        3 |
|  2 |      1 |          4 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |          5 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |          6 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |          7 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |          8 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |          9 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         10 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         11 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         12 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         13 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         14 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         15 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         16 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         17 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         18 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         19 |        2 |
|  2 |      1 |         20 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |          1 |        3 |
|  3 |      1 |          2 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |          3 |        3 |
|  3 |      1 |          4 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |          5 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |          6 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |          7 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |          8 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |          9 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         10 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         11 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         12 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         13 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         14 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         15 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         16 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         17 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         18 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         19 |        2 |
|  3 |      1 |         20 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |          1 |        3 |
|  4 |      1 |          2 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |          3 |        3 |
|  4 |      1 |          4 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |          5 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |          6 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |          7 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |          8 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |          9 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         10 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         11 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         12 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         13 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         14 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         15 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         16 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         17 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         18 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         19 |        2 |
|  4 |      1 |         20 |        2 |
|----|--------|------------|----------|
```

You may need to change the column names to match your tables.